# Computing number of people with the same name and date of birth base on sample data.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Country has population of 40 000 000 people.
I have sample with data of 1 500 000 people from this country.
In this sample 1.9% of people have "pair" (one or more) who has the same first name, last name and date of birth (but is not the same person).
Can i compute with this data how many people in whole population have pair with the same name and date of birth?

Comment: When you say "pair", do you mean "at least one other person"?  Note that there could be more than one, which complicates matters.

Comment: Thanks for your question. I have meant one or more.

Comment: Whether you can make an inference from the sample depends on how that sample is chosen. For instance if all of the $1 500 000$ people come from one region in the country, which has a culture that uses a limited pool of names, then the $1.9\%$ value is unlikely to apply to the country as a whole. But if the sample was chosen uniformly at random from the entire country, then it is probable that the $1.9%$ value is close to the percentage for the entire country.